# Make a Listerner to detect Memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-management

i wish to make a `Listener` will watch/Track RAM Usage.

I know that in C# we can get the Working Usage using

```
  public static class PerformanceInfo
  {
      [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool GetPerformanceInfo([Out] out PerformanceInformation       PerformanceInformation, [In] int Size);

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      public struct PerformanceInformation
      {
        public int Size;
        public IntPtr CommitTotal;
        public IntPtr CommitLimit;
        public IntPtr CommitPeak;
        public IntPtr PhysicalTotal;
        public IntPtr PhysicalAvailable;
        public IntPtr SystemCache;
        public IntPtr KernelTotal;
        public IntPtr KernelPaged;
        public IntPtr KernelNonPaged;
        public IntPtr PageSize;
        public int HandlesCount;
        public int ProcessCount;
        public int ThreadCount;
      }

      public static Int64 GetPhysicalAvailableMemoryInMiB()
      {
          PerformanceInformation pi = new PerformanceInformation();
          if (GetPerformanceInfo(out pi, Marshal.SizeOf(pi)))
          {
            return Convert.ToInt64((pi.PhysicalAvailable.ToInt64() * pi.PageSize.ToInt64() / 1048576));
          }
          else
          {
            return -1;
          }

      }

      public static Int64 GetTotalMemoryInMiB()
      {
        PerformanceInformation pi = new PerformanceInformation();
        if (GetPerformanceInfo(out pi, Marshal.SizeOf(pi)))
        {
          return Convert.ToInt64((pi.PhysicalTotal.ToInt64() * pi.PageSize.ToInt64() / 1048576));
        }
        else
        {
          return -1;
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

No this listener should track the RAM USAGE EVEry Second and if its greater than the specified %age then it should `Kill Some Processes` or should provide some notification to my App (WPF app) to kill some specific processes

How can i make a piece of code constantlr listen to sytem and then invoke some actions

Any help in this regard would be great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use on of Timer classes. Like [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or even simple `Thread.Sleep(1000)` will be ok (assuming your code runs on seprate non-UI thread).